# sum method on query multiple columns based on id

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a sports team app and trying to sum (total) the goals scored for each player throughout the season. I have a query as follows:

```
    $GMC = DB::table('matchcards')->where('grade_id', $gradeId)->select('id')->get();
        foreach($GMC as $object)
        {
            $arrays[] =  (array) $object;
        }
        $GMCX = collect($arrays)->flatten();

    foreach ($GMCX as $mc) { //Loop 1 - Get a list of all matchcards for this grade

        $im = DB::table('matchcards')->distinct()->select('capt', 'gk', 'player3', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6', 'player7', 'player8'
            , 'player9', 'player10', 'player11', 'player12', 'player13', 'player14', 'player15', 'player16')->where('id', $mc)->get();

        foreach ($im as $object2) {
            $arrays2[] = (array)$object2;
        }

        $imx = collect($arrays2)->flatten(); //Gets all the PlayedIDs from above loop
    } //end of Loop 1

        $gp ='0'; $gamesplayed= array(); $collection = collect(); $M='0';
        foreach ($imx as $p) { //loop 2 - take each id and count games played
            $_GET['p'] = $p;
            $pcount = DB::table('matchcards')->where('capt', $p)->where('grade_id', $gradeId)->orWhere('gk', $p)->orWhere('player3', $p)
                ->orWhere('player4', $p)->orWhere('player5', $p)->orWhere('player6', $p)->orWhere('player7', $p)
                ->orWhere('player8', $p)->orWhere('player9', $p)->orWhere('player10', $p)->orWhere('player11', $p)
                ->orWhere('player12', $p)->orWhere('player13', $p)->orWhere('player14', $p)->orWhere('player15', $p)
                ->orWhere('player16', $p)->get();
            $gp = count($pcount);
            if (count($pcount) > 0){ //Get Players Full Name
                $pn = DB::table('players')->select('id', 'fname', 'lname')->where('id', $p)->get();
                if (count($pn)>0) {
                    $pname = $pn[0]->fname." ".$pn[0]->lname;
                }

   $M = DB::table('matchcards')
                    ->select('p1scorer', 'p1goals','p2scorer', 'p2goals', 'p3scorer', 'p3goals','p4scorer', 'p4goals', 'p5scorer', 'p5goals','p6scorer', 'p6goals')
                    ->where('grade_id', '=', $gradeId)
                    ->Where(function ($query) {
                        $p = $_GET['p'];
                        $query->where('p1scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p2scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p3scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p4scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p5scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p6scorer', '=', $p);
                    })
                   ->sum(DB::raw('p1goals + p2goals + p3goals + p4goals + p5goals + p6goals'));
                   //->select(DB::raw('sum(p1goals + p2goals + p3goals + p4goals + p5goals + p6goals ) as goals_scored'))->get();
```

}

```
           //Add all objects into collection/
            $collection->push(['id' => $p, 'gp' => $gp, 'pname' => $pname, 'gs' => $M]);

        } //end of loop 2

        $unique = $collection->unique();  //Removed duplicate IDs
```

It is returning ONLY the people who scored - so its half working. I just dont know HOW to add up JUST the goals for that user (across 6 possible columns). At the moment, my query adds ALL goals for that particular match/game (or row in DB) to the player.

There are 6 possible columns each matchcard for coaches to select up to 6 players who scored (hence, p1scorer and p1goals belong together, and p2scorer and p2goals belong together... Each week the playerID can be in any one of the P1scorer to p6scorer columns - but never duplicated on same row). Scenario example week 1 (row 1) p1scorer is 17 (ID of player) who scored 2 goals (so 2 inside p1goals). Also p2scorer is 5 who scored 1 goal - so 3 goals in the row total - want to send to array for that row ( id: 17 goals: 2 } { id: 5 goals: 1 }, and loop through all other rows and ADD goals to the existing tally for each individual who scored throughout the season.

Hoping someone might be able to help me here... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Input;

```
$p = $request->p;
```

**OR**

```
$p = Input::get(p);   


 $M = DB::table('matchcards')
                    ->select('p1scorer', 'p1goals','p2scorer', 'p2goals', 'p3scorer', 'p3goals','p4scorer', 'p4goals', 'p5scorer', 'p5goals','p6scorer', 'p6goals')
                    ->where('grade_id', '=', $gradeId)
                    ->Where(function ($query) use($p) {

                        $query->where('p1scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p2scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p3scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p4scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p5scorer', '=', $p)
                            ->orWhere('p6scorer', '=', $p);
                    });

                   ->sum(DB::raw('p1goals + p2goals + p3goals + p4goals + p5goals + p6goals'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help/suggestion... When I move the GET command outside the query, the $p in the sub query returns "undefined variable" which is why I had it inside the query. That part does however seem to be working fine (in that I am getting only the goal scorers in the array - my problem/challenge is adding up the goals associated with the $p (ID) in one of six columns throughout approx 20 row returns. thats where I am stuck... cheers

Comment: @Jimmy Let me check it

Comment: @Jimmy Please check my updated answer for $p variable

Comment: Use of undefined constant p - assumed 'p'

Note: $p is not coming in via an input (hence the error). I run an initial loop to get all the playerIDs from the table first, create a collection which just contains all the ID's ($p) - and then loop through the matchcards above searching for which of those ids scored (got that part working) and then try to count HOW many goals each ID scored (I cannot get this value).